# blazor app works in debug mode but not in release

Tags: .net, .net-core, blazor, dotnet-httpclient

Consider this Blazor, minimal API app.

We have an API "/complaint/getorder" added into the pipeline

```
app.MapGet("/complaint/getorder", (Guid fileid, CancellationToken ct, [FromServices] ITrackTraceApiClient client) => client.GetOrder(ct))
```

The blazor app uses IFlurlClient to call the service.

```
    private readonly IFlurlClient _client = .......;

    public async Task<Order?> GetOrder(Guid fileId, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var req = _client.Request("complaint", "getorderbyfileid", fileId);
        // DEBUG
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(await req.GetStringAsync());
        return await req.GetJsonAsync<Order?>(ct);
    }
```

Now the index.razor has page "/" directive at the top and simply does a NavigateTo to another page where the service call is done.

```
@page "/"

@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/order/new");
    }
```

This works fine in debug mode, WriteLineAsync prints a json of an order.

But when the app is run in NON DEBUG mode and the service is called it returns the html of index.razor again! And then GetJsonAsync throws of course.

It happens with .net7.0 and .net8.0, I noticed it when moving to .net8.0.

One difference when switching to net8.0 is that launchurl defaults did not work anymore.

```
"launchUrl": "/"
```

The razor page would print "endpoint not found" and the url in the browser shows double slashes "https://localhost:7096//".

This worked in net7.0. The brwoser shows briefly double slahes and then Navigates to the page.

So I changed it to empty url `"launchUrl": ""` and the app works except for the API call in NON DEBUG mode!

A long story, but what could be wrong here? A wrong redirect in a page, something with net8.0 changes?